# How to set variable value through AppDelegate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UIViewController` in `Main.storyboard` and set it's identifier to `settings`. I reference `Main.storyboard` and get the view controller in `AppDelegate` and then set the value of a variable which is located in view controller but it returns nil.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let settingViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "settings") as UIViewController? {
        let settingVC = settingViewController as! SettingViewController
        settingVC.moc = persistendContainer.viewContext
    }

    return true
}
```

And I have following variable in `SettingViewController`:

```
var moc: NSManagedObjectContext!
```

I confirmed that I am able to get `Main.storyboard`, `SettingViewController` and `persistentContainer.viewContext` has value.

Comment: remove `as UIViewController?` You don't need it. Just write: if let `settingViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "settings") as SettingViewController`.

Comment: @Honey `Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'SettingsViewController?' in coercion`

Comment: My bad. you should have used `as? SettingViewController`

Comment: FYI, `if let settingViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "settings") as? SettingViewController {` will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating a new settings `UIViewController` successfully, but then nothing happens with it after that.  Later on your app will create a Settings viewController through the storyboard, but that will be a different one.

The better way to do this is to create an accessible place for your viewController to access the `moc` variable rather than trying to pass it in in advance.  This is usually done for you if you let Xcode create the project with CoreData set up.  You can say `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext` from any viewController in your app and get a pointer to that `moc`.